# How to post a form with MVC controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I post a form to an external site using an ASP.NET MVC controller?

**EDIT:** Ok... I have a view with some data on it. After the user completes the form I need to do a postback with a specified form format to an external site (like for paypal). After I posted the constructed form I need to redirect the action to a new view

Comment: can u clarify a bit more on what you are trying to do?

Comment: Ok... I have a view with some data on it. After the user completes the form I need to do a postback with a specified form format to an external site (like for paypal). After I posted the constructed form I need to redirect the action to a new view.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do the POST on the server-side..

of which this guy has written a helper class to do [Http Post in C#](https://web.archive.org/web/20210123193021/http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2006/04/21/76044.aspx) ([pastebin-ed](https://pastebin.com/f15346568)). Check it out.

Send the post with the PostSubmitter class and just render your view normally.

Basically, in situation like this one would create a HttpWebRequest, set Method to post and write the post data to the request stream. But the linked code already does that for you in a nice and cozy way.

So no need rewire anything.

Comment: Please [edit] the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can just manually set the action in the form tag to wherever you want to post to...

edit -

That is to say that you should manually create the form tag..

Instead of:

```
<% using (Html.Form<Controller>("Action", c => c.Method())) { %>
```

You should use:

```
<form action="http://www.someotherwebsite.com/action">
```

Answer (score -2):

How about sending a redirect to the browser.